# R summarise not working with distinct clause

Tags: r, dplyr

```
ACCOUNT = c(M205109, M205109, M201212, M205668, M207954, M208966, M203465, M207622, M201869, M201869)
age = c(20, 20, 18, 29, 21, 19, 19, 23, 22, 22)
```

The code I am using

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(lubridate)

age_summary_all <- data %>%
  distinct(ACCOUNT) %>%
  summarise(min = min(age, na.rm=TRUE),
            q1 = quantile(age, 0.25, na.rm=TRUE),
            median = median(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            mean = mean(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            q3 = quantile(age, 0.75, na.rm=TRUE),
            max = max(age, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I get this error:

> Error in `summarise()`: ! Problem while computing `min = min(age, na.rm = TRUE)`. Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_summarise()`: !
> object 'age' not found

The really odd thing is that exactly the same code runs fine if the distinct is replaced by a group_by clause referring to a different column, but I need to run the analysis on unique individuals - the nature of the data is such that individual accounts are likely to have more than one entry in the data table. So, for the example above I would expect n = 8 for the summarise clause.

All the packages are definitely up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinct` needs `.keep_all=T` in this case.

> .keep_all: If ‘TRUE’, keep all variables in ‘.data’. If a combination
> of ‘...’ is not distinct, this keeps the first row of values.

Call without `.keep_all=T`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  distinct(ACCOUNT)
# A tibble: 8 × 1
  ACCOUNT
  <chr>
1 M205109
2 M201212
3 M205668
4 M207954
5 M208966
6 M203465
7 M207622
8 M201869
```

Call with `.keep_all=T`

```
data %>% 
  distinct(ACCOUNT, .keep_all=T)
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  ACCOUNT   age
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 M205109    20
2 M201212    18
3 M205668    29
4 M207954    21
5 M208966    19
6 M203465    19
7 M207622    23
8 M201869    22
```

```
data %>%
  distinct(ACCOUNT, .keep_all=T) %>%
  summarise(min = min(age, na.rm=TRUE),
            q1 = quantile(age, 0.25, na.rm=TRUE),
            median = median(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            mean = mean(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            q3 = quantile(age, 0.75, na.rm=TRUE),
            max = max(age, na.rm=TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 × 6
    min    q1 median  mean    q3   max
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    18    19   20.5  21.4  22.2    29
```

##### Data

```
data <- structure(list(ACCOUNT = c("M205109", "M205109", "M201212", "M205668",
"M207954", "M208966", "M203465", "M207622", "M201869", "M201869"
), age = c(20, 20, 18, 29, 21, 19, 19, 23, 22, 22)), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks - there are a lot of duplicated values in the other columns, not least several thousand people with the same age, so that explains my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
account <- c("M205109", "M205109", "M201212", "M205668", "M207954", "M208966", "M203465", "M207622", "M201869", "M201869")
age <- c(20, 20, 18, 29, 21, 19, 19, 23, 22, 22)

library(dplyr)    

data <- data.frame(account , age)

age_summary_all <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(account) %>%
  summarise(min = min(age, na.rm=TRUE),
            q1 = quantile(age, 0.25, na.rm=TRUE),
            median = median(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            mean = mean(age,na.rm=TRUE),
            q3 = quantile(age, 0.75, na.rm=TRUE),
            max = max(age, na.rm=TRUE))

age_summary_all

# A tibble: 8 x 7
  account   min    q1 median  mean    q3   max
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 M201212    18    18     18    18    18    18
2 M201869    22    22     22    22    22    22
3 M203465    19    19     19    19    19    19
4 M205109    20    20     20    20    20    20
5 M205668    29    29     29    29    29    29
6 M207622    23    23     23    23    23    23
7 M207954    21    21     21    21    21    21
8 M208966    19    19     19    19    19    19
```